# Audio Slowly Desynchronizing When Segmenting

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, synchronization

I use ffmpeg's ability to segment video while I record so I can record constantly without my hard drive filling up.

It works really well, expect the audio desynchronizes from the video when the file segments. The video seems to be uninterrupted but I can actually hear a tiny jump in the audio when I join segments later on. One would think that ffmpeg would store packets in a queue during segmentation so nothing is lost but that doesn't seem to be the case... Any way I could force it to do something like that?

Here is my current block:

```
ffmpeg -y -thread_queue_size 5096 -f dshow -video_size 3440x1440 -rtbufsize 2147.48M -framerate 100 -pixel_format nv12 ^
-itsoffset 00:00:00.012 -i video="Video (00 Pro Capture HDMI 4K+)" -thread_queue_size 5096 -guess_layout_max 0 -f dshow ^
-rtbufsize 2147.48M -i audio="SPDIF/ADAT (1+2) (RME Fireface UC)" -map 0:0,1:0 -map 1:0 -c:v h264_nvenc -preset: llhp ^
-pix_fmt nv12 -b:v 250M -minrate 250M -maxrate 250M -bufsize 250M -b:a 384k -ac 2 -r 100 -vsync 1 ^
-max_muxing_queue_size 5096 -segment_time 600 -segment_wrap 9 -f segment C:\Users\djcim\Videos\PC\PC\PC%02d.mp4
```

I am delaying the video stream because right out the gate it's a little bit ahead of the audio.

PS: aresample or async seem to have no effect or at least not a desirable one.

Comment: I know that IPTV and also CCTV uses the raw MPEG-TS output which is easier to segment and piece back together as it is container-less. So my suggestion would be to choose a raw container-less output.

Comment: MPEG-TS *is* a container.

Comment: So Mulvya do you disagree with WLGfx or were you just correcting a portion of the comment? 

Is the extension for MPEG-TS just .ts? A little reluctant to change video formats as I would have to re-encode them to something adobe premiere uses.

Comment: So I switched to .ts and it didn't seem to help much, but then I found some weird behavior.

If I concat the two first segments in FFMPEG and directly compare it to the two parts placed next to each-other in Adobe Premiere the first segment matches the concatenated clip but the second segment does not.

It's almost like ffmpeg is injecting a certain amount of silence or duplicating frames during segmentation but knows how to line everything back up with concat...

This is undesirable, I am hoping to continuously record with the ability to edit a single segment without dependencies.

Comment: On a ts streams that I've worked with the audio is usually about a second ahead or behind (can't remember) of the video stream if that's any help. I hope you are able to find a solution. I've always been able to piece together ts streams.

Comment: It would seem that the audio is being segmented right before the video or something... Maybe something to do with time stamps or segment segmenting the video on a key frame but the audio at a different time? Driving me crazy.

Comment: WLGfx is definitely on to something, when I initially changed to .ts I was still having sync issues but after adding reset_timestamps 1 to the segment command audio is staying in-sync throughout segmentation. reset_timestamps 1 only works in combination with a .ts, it wont work with an MP4, maybe a bug? However this did cause another issue, my clips are no longer 10 minutes in length they are 9:57. This wouldn't be a huge issue but I actually have multiple segmented outputs and I'd like to keep them all the same length. 60fps segments are 9:55 in length 100FPS segments are 9:57 not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using -reset_timestamps in conjunction with encoding .ts instead of .mp4 has mostly solved this issue. -reset_timestamps does not appear to work when encoding .mp4, not sure why, maybe a bug?

I say mostly because audio still drifts around a frame after the first segment, but not exponentially. I find audio de-synced by one frame acceptable. Although I should mention now when I try to concat the clips back together I have audio drift issues, not always, but sometimes. Using aresample=async=250 fixes the drift after concat but you can hear the audio stretch a bit when doing so. Can't expect everything to work perfectly.

```
ffmpeg - y -thread_queue_size 9999 -indexmem 9999 -guess_layout_max 0 -f dshow -video_size 3440x1440 -rtbufsize 2147.48M ^
-framerate 200 -pixel_format nv12 -i video="Video (00 Pro Capture HDMI 4K+)":audio="SPDIF/ADAT (1+2) (RME Fireface UC)" ^
-map 0:0,0:1 -map 0:1 -flags +cgop -force_key_frames expr:gte(t,n_forced*2) -c:v h264_nvenc -preset: llhp -pix_fmt nv12 ^
-b:v 250M -minrate 250M -maxrate 250M -bufsize 250M -c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 384k -ac 2 -r 100 ^
-af "atrim=0.038, asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS, aresample=async=250" -vsync 1 -ss 00:00:01.096 -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 ^
-f segment -segment_time 600 -segment_wrap 9 -reset_timestamps 1 C:\Users\djcim\Videos\PC\PC\PC%02d.ts
```